# How do I merge messages using either OR or JOIN?

Tags: mysql

I want to show the conversation between person A and person B only.

Type in Facebook messages ...

The problem is that my query is returning all messages and not only the ones between the selected people.

How do I fix this with OR or JOIN?

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    msgs 
WHERE   usr_to = 'myself'
AND     author_msg = 'he' 
OR      author_msg = 'myself' 
AND     usr_to = 'he' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: Okay a little more info. Post the schema. What are you trying to join and with what

Comment: I want to add posts. Type mine and it ... The ones he sent me and he sent me, like on facebook. N sidebar of that page messages or even one type of header, which has the messages from facebook! Type it.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Not working friends... Exemple:  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM msgs JOIN accounts ON msgs.author_msg = accounts.user WHERE (msg_to = '".$this_is_me."' OR msg_to = accounts.user) AND (author_msg = '".$this_is_me."' OR author_msg = accounts.msg_to) order by msgs.id desc limit 8", $mysql);  Demo: msgs facebook

Comment: @CintiaCorreia [then update your question with the information about the accounts table as it was not listed before. Don't forget to list what are the fields you have on both tables otherwise it will be even hard to understand you.](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18158415/edit)

Comment: I want to type Facebook. In the pages of posts in the sidebar when viewing a list of messages you have sent to the user or that he sent you. Ai shows or his message or his. How do the query in Mysql? example: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1401447870079454&set=a.1401447376746170.1073741830.100006427635180&type=3&src=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash3%2F1098071_1401447870079454_957864210_n.jpg&size=318%2C307

Comment: I want to list the messages type facebook. Example: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1401447870079454&set=a.1401447376746170.1073741830.100006427635180&type=3&src=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash3%2F1098071_1401447870079454_957864210_n.jpg&size=318%2C307
The usr_to and usr_author as the two pillars of Mysql for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use brackets to group the conditions:

```
$mysql = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * 
    FROM msgs 
    WHERE
        (usr_to = 'myself' AND author_msg = 'he')
        OR
        (author_msg = 'myself' AND usr_to = 'he') 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT 12",
    $mysql
);
```

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MSGS.* JOIN ACCOUNTS ON ACCOUNTS.msg_to = MSGS.msg_author WHERE (MSGS.msg_to, MSGS.msg_author) IN (('".$this_is_me."', MSGS.msg_author), (MSGS.msg_author, '".$this_is_me."')) GROUP BY MSGS.msg_author ORDER BY MSGS.id DESC LIMIT 12", $mysql);

while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){



}

//The group by should do it but do not. Displays the last message me or while the user listed.

Comment: @CintiaCorreia: My answer solves your "filtering" problem (the one you originally posted). To solve new problems add new questions. But if you are grouping by `msg_author`, do not expect several items with the same author.

Comment: I want to list the messages type facebook. Example: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1401447870079454&set=a.1401447376746170.1073741830.100006427635180&type=3&src=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash3%2F1098071_1401447870079454_957864210_n.jpg&size=318%2C307
The usr_to and usr_author as the two pillars of Mysql for reference.

Comment: @CintiaCorreia: Sorry, I do not understand what you are saying. What do you mean by "messages type facebook"? Do you want to display the conversation like Facebook does? Or messages containing word "facebook"? What do you mean by "two pillars of MySQL for reference"? Do you mean conditions in MySQL query? Or what? That is pretty ambigous.

Answer (score 0):

The `AND` and `OR` logical operators have different precedences (`OR` is lower than `AND`), so in general when you use `OR` and `AND` together you need to group them with parentheses:

```
SELECT * FROM msgs
WHERE (usr_to = 'myself' AND author_msg = 'he') OR
      (author_msg = 'myself' AND usr_to = 'he')
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 12
```

You can also use `IN` and specify a set of valid combinations; this saves you from worrying about `AND` / `OR` precedence:

```
SELECT * FROM msgs
WHERE (usr_to, author_msg) IN (('myself', 'he'), ('he', 'myself))
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: But like I have no way of knowing who is the author of the message in the function, how do I go to him? I have to use JOIN? Type the message will be to min, ai mysql will list my mensanges, it will show my last message or last this author. Then as if to catch the author in the role?

Comment: Doesn't the `author_msg` show who the author is? If not, there isn't enough information in your question so you'll need to add (1) table structures, (2) sample data, and (3) expected output.

Comment: I want to type Facebook. In the pages of posts in the sidebar when viewing a list of messages you have sent to the user or that he sent you. Ai shows or his message or his. How do the query in Mysql? example: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=1401447870079454&set=a.1401447376746170.1073741830.100006427635180&type=3&src=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash3%2F1098071_1401447870079454_957864210_n.jpg&size=318%2C307

Comment: I understand, but I can't figure out the query if I don't know what your data looks like. The query I gave above (and the query in the other answer) will both show messages between `myself` and `he` based on the information in your question. If it isn't working I'll need more information. I already know what facebook looks like; I need to know what your tables look like.

Comment: Tabela Mysql: id - usr_to - usr_author - date - msg

Comment: I'm using their function more it is listing all posts of author and recipient of the message. I wanted that listed only once, and show the description of the last message sent. If the recipient said the last message, then shows his message. Type on facebook!

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand, but try something like this at the end of the query: `ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`. If that doesn't work, maybe you can query all the author/recipient messages in MySQL and use PHP to find the message you want.